# Make text a link/annotation to invoke goTo other page action in PDF

Tags: pdf, syncfusion

How do I make plain text in a PDF a link to another part of the pdf document?
Currently, I'm post processing a PDF.  I've identified two pages  that should link pack to each other base on if two numbers (text object) are found in the page.

Is there a way I can convert that text to a clickable local link?

Comment: the text itself is irrelevant, what you need are the coordinates of the box around the text.  What library are you using to do your PDF post-processing?

Comment: The coordinates of the box around the text does not appear to be something that syncfusion provides as part of its text extraction.

Comment: @PatrickGallot it is syncfusion. Potentially, use a different lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have checked the reported query "*Make text a link/annotation to invoke goto other page action in PDF*" and prepared a test sample to meet your requirement. In this sample we have used `PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation` to navigate the internal document by click on text. Please check the sample and it is available in the below link for your reference.

Please find the sample from [the following link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/sample-1414827259.zip).

Also please find the below [UG documentation link](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-annotations) to more details about `PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation`.

Code in link:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics;
using Syncfusion.Pdf.Interactive;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string DataPathOutput
        {
            get
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\..\..\Output\"))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\..\..\Output\");
                return System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\..\..\Output\";
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creates a new PDF document
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

            // Creates a first page 
            PdfPage firstPage = document.Pages.Add();

            PdfFont font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.Courier, 12f);
            PdfBrush brush = PdfBrushes.Black;
            PdfGraphics graphics1 = firstPage.Graphics;

            string inputText1 = "Sample Text-1";
            graphics1.DrawString(inputText1, font, brush, 10, 40);

            // Measure string size to use same size for annotation
            SizeF size1 = font.MeasureString(inputText1);
            RectangleF rectangle1 = new RectangleF(10, 40, size1.Width, size1.Height);

            // Creates a second page
            PdfPage secondPage = document.Pages.Add();
            PdfGraphics graphics2 = secondPage.Graphics;

            string secondPageInput = "Sample Text-2";
            graphics2.DrawString(secondPageInput, font, brush, 10, 40);

            // Measure string size to use same size for annotation
            SizeF size2 = font.MeasureString(inputText1);
            RectangleF rectangle2 = new RectangleF(10, 40, size2.Width, size2.Height);

            // Add annotation for firstpage to link second page of PdfDocumet
            PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation firstAnnotation = new PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation(rectangle1);
            firstAnnotation.Color = new PdfColor(Color.Transparent);
            firstAnnotation.Destination = new PdfDestination(secondPage);
            // Use below comment for link specific part of page
            //firstAnnotation.Destination.Location = new Point(10, 40);
            firstPage.Annotations.Add(firstAnnotation);

            // Add annotation for second page to link first page of PdfDocumet
            PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation secondAnnotation = new PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation(rectangle2);
            secondAnnotation.Color = new PdfColor(Color.Transparent);
            secondAnnotation.Destination = new PdfDestination(firstPage);
            // Use below comment for link specific part of page
            //secondAnnotation.Destination.Location = new Point(10, 40);
            secondPage.Annotations.Add(secondAnnotation);

            // Save document on mentioned location
            document.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(DataPathOutput, "Output.pdf"));
            document.Close(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot

Comment: Links will eventually rot, could you summarize the contents of them in your answer?